# Iterating through keys in Redis

Tags: redis

I have just started with Redis. My DB contains about 1 billion records. Using `HKEYS *` results in an out of memory error.

Is there a way to iterate through keys? Something like `HKEYS *` but with a limit n?

**Edit:**

I am now using a loop which matches a pattern

```
for c in '1234567890abcedf':
    r.keys(c + '*')
```

Comment: You meant `KEYS *`, right? `HKEYS` is for listing keys of a hash. Anyway, if you use `KEYS` in your code there is a big chance you're doing something wrong, i.e. not using Redis as it should be used. `KEYS` should be treated as a debugging function only. You're probably not using the right redis datatype. Please describe your problem (e.g. why you need to list the keys) and I might be able to help choose the right redis database that matches your problem.

Comment: See the answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127736/redis-sorted-sets-and-best-way-to-store-uids/9195219#9195219 - you have an example of scalable key iteration there.

Answer (score 8):

Available since Redis 2.8.0 are the cursor based Redis iteration commands (SCAN, HSCAN etc) that let you iterate efficiently over billions of keys.
For your specific case, the start using HSCAN instead of HKEYS/HGETALL. It is [efficient, cheap on server resources and scales very well](http://redis.io/commands/keys). You can even add a pattern to [HSCAN](http://redis.io/commands/hscan) unlike HKEYS.

e.g.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HMSET hash0 key0 value0 key1 value1 entry0 data0 entry1 data1
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> HSCAN hash0 0 MATCH key* 
1) "0"
2) 1) "key0"
   2) "value0"
   3) "key1"
   4) "value1"
127.0.0.1:6379> HSCAN hash0 0 
1) "0"
2) 1) "key0"
   2) "value0"
   3) "key1"
   4) "value1"
   5) "entry0"
   6) "data0"
   7) "entry1"
   8) "data1"
```

Comment: upvoted! i understand how this works but my keys dont have a pattern, they are integers from 1 to 1000 and contain a large string each, i dont want to hgetall in memory ,is there any way i can loop through them

Comment: @PirateApp Don't think there is a way that the MATCH command will take a pattern that will match the sort of keys you have. Folks usually create a "namespace hierarchy" in Redis keyspace to bring some order to their store. Consider adding prefixes to your keys.

On the other hand, if you already know your keys, you can fetch them by specifically too, no?

Answer (score 1):

You can't iterate over redis keys directly, but you can accomplish something very similar by transactionally writing the `key` portion of your key-value pair to a sorted set at the same time you write your `key`-`value` pair.

Downstream, you would "iterate" over your keys by reading `n` `key`s from the sorted set, and then transactionally removing them from the sorted set at the same time as you remove the associated key-value pair.

I wrote up an example with some C# code here: http://rianjs.net/2014/04/how-to-iterate-over-redis-keys/

You could do this in any language that has a redis library that supports transactions.

Comment: SCAN did not exist when this question was asked.

Comment: I've added a point to this answer since it was correct at the time. People should be aware of temporal answers before marking them down.

Comment: SCAN can be very slow.   having a subkey-set could be the right way to go.  imagine millions of keys partitioned into groups of 10, and you want to iterate one partition.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, at the current time, year 2012, the simple answer is no, however, with lua scripting you could do it, although that is not direct redis in the strictest sense.

Comment: I believe this was not available in 2012 @Cosmin

Answer (score 0):

For iterating through keys:

```
SCAN cursor [MATCH pattern] [COUNT count]
```

http://redis.io/commands/scan

For iterating through the values of a hash

`HSCAN key cursor [MATCH pattern] [COUNT count]`

http://redis.io/commands/hscan