# paging through entries in redis hash

Tags: redis

I couldn't find a way to "page" through redis hashes ([doc](http://redis.io/commands)).

I've got ~5million hash entries in 1 redis db. I am trying to iterate through all of them without having to resort to building a list of entry keys.

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

Since all the redis hash commands require the key element. You need to store your set of keys to page your hash.

Answer (score 3):

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127736/redis-sorted-sets-and-best-way-to-store-uids/9195219#9195219) for an example of key iteration by using extra sets.

There is no way to avoid storing extra sets (or lists) and still iterate on a huge number of keys. The KEYS command is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same requirement of [Redis Hash Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46954129/redis-hash-pagination) and yes it is possible to page through redis hash using [HSCAN](https://redis.io/commands/hscan) command. Detailed documentation of the same is present at [SCAN](https://redis.io/commands/scan).

Usage:  `Hscan <your key/hash name> <cursor-id>  count <page-size>`. 
cursor id which should be passed initially is 0 and it returns a `cursor-id` and data which is of `page-size`. The cursor id returned needs to be passed in the subsequent call for fetching subsequent data.