# Redis Hash Pagination

Tags: redis, pagination, spring-data-redis

I am using the *Redis Hash*, in which I am storing student id as the key (which is not numeric), the value is POJO of student data. now I need **redis-pagination** i.e. I don't care about the students' order but I want to fetch only some students data in one go. can I do this in Redis? if for supporting the pagination some modification in the data structure is required that would be ok too.

P.S. I am using *spring-data-redis*. but the solution without it would be ok too. basically, I want to find out whether redis supports pagination for hashes.

Comment: Have you able to implement this for spring data redis. If so please provide your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for the [`HSCAN`](https://redis.io/commands/hscan) command, which lets you page through a hash using a cursor. It has the same interface as the global key [`SCAN`](https://redis.io/commands/scan) command, so look there for examples.

I'm not familiar with `spring-data-redis` but it might have some nice wrapper for this functionality. Otherwise, drop down to whatever redis library it runs on and execute it directly.